# Assigning a parent to mesh causes mesh to change location

Tags: transforms, parent

I have an Empty, not located at the origin. When I parent a mesh to the empty, the mesh changes location. I don't understand this functionality in Blender.
Is there an option to prevent this from happening? Right now I make sure to leave the Empty at the origin to prevent the mesh from relocating during parenting.

[image]

Comment: How do you apply the parent? It looks like the object changes coordinates from global to local coordinates of the empty

Comment: In the lower right hand corner of the screenshot there is an input for "Parent". With the cube selected, I then choose the name of the parent, in this case is "Empty". Why, is there are better approach for doing this?

Comment: That's the problem, you're just switching the coordinates, instead select the cube then the empty while holding SHIFT button, and apply parent using CTRL+P

Comment: Ok, thanks that works now. I was going about it the wrong way.( Can someone please make that an accepted answer?)

Comment: it is like that, but isn't it weird? that "parent" field lets you choose an object... and it becomes the parent, exactly as when you do ctrl+P parenting... it is not so clear...