# Why does my object offset when setting its parent with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, parent

By using

```
bpy.data.objects['object1'].parent = bpy.data.objects['object2']
```

[image]
to parent one object to another the parented object gets a weird offset.
Why does this happen and how can i fix this?

Comment: I asked a similar question before: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62897/assigning-a-parent-to-mesh-causes-mesh-to-change-location
The method you are using is equivalent to assigning the parent in the "Relations" section. This causes mesh to change location. The other way is using CTRL-P to do the parenting. It looks like the Python code might be:
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(...)

Comment: It would be nice if they could eliminate the 5-minute rule for editing comments on this site. Not sure the reasoning behind this.       Anyway, here is a link to another questions which looks like it has an explanation to the code: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects

Comment: Possible dupe of http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29148/15543